# check the value of Increment Arrows on Input using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple input with increment Arrows buttons, I want to check the input value so that if I increase the number to one display alert message, and if I decreased to zero display another alert message,

here is the input with increment Arrows buttons:

```html
<button style="margin-left:20%;" type='button' onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp();" class="plus"></button>
<input id="myInput" min="0" name="quantity" value="0" type="number" />
<button style="margin-left:20%;" type='button' onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown();"></button>
```

here is what I tried:

```js
if (document.getElementById("myInput").value === "1") {
  alert("one");
} else if (document.getElementById("myInput").value === "0") {
  alert("zero");
}
```

updated code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function validate3() {

    var input = document.querySelector("#quantity");
    var parent = document.querySelector(".input-control");

    function alertQuantity(value) {
      if (value > '1') alert("one");
      else if (value === '0') alert("zero");
    }

    parent.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      var target = event.target;
      if (target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
        if (target.id === 'stepUp') {
          input.stepUp();
        } else if (target.id === 'stepDown') {
          input.stepDown();
        }
        alertQuantity(input.value);
      }
    })

    input.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
      alertQuantity(event.target.value);
    })
  }
</script>


<div class="input-control">
  <button type='button' id="stepUp" onclick="validate3() ">+</button>
  <input id="quantity" min="0" name="quantity" value="0" type="number" />
  <button type='button' id="stepDown" onclick="validate3() ">-</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Where did you put that if-elseif block?

Comment: @choz Not true for me; I get strings.

Comment: Right, sorry for the misled. I think I got mixed up with something else.

Comment: 1.Please attach a function on click input type and move the if and else if block to the function. 2. also change the if condition to an integer. it must work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, keep in mind always avoid using inline handlers to stick with [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) approach, to make you could cleaner and maintainable.

To achieve what are you looking for you can simply add event listeners to your buttons and also your input to check whether they met your condition or not. You can simply do this with [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Also, to create a better performance on your application it is usually better to avoid attaching multiple same-ish events to your DOM, so, it is better to use [event delegation approach](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) which means to add a single event listener to the parent element then check whether the clicked element is the same that you want or not.

So, your final code would be something like this:

#### ES6 version

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#quantity")
const parent = document.querySelector(".input-control")

function alertQuantity(value) {
  if (value === '1') alert('one')
  else if (value === '0') alert('zero')
}

parent.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  const {
    target
  } = event
  if (target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    if (target.id === 'stepUp') {
      input.stepUp();
    } else if (target.id === 'stepDown') {
      input.stepDown();
    }
    alertQuantity(input.value)
  }
})

input.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  alertQuantity(event.target.value)
})
```

```html
<div class="input-control">
  <button type='button' id="stepUp">+</button>
  <input id="quantity" min="0" name="quantity" value="0" type="number" />
  <button type='button' id="stepDown">-</button>
</div>
```

#### ES5 version

<sup>Semi colons, if statement blockings, and the script tags just added for extra readability and for the OP situation. So, these things are nothing to do with the ECMAScript versions.</sup>

```html
<div class="input-control">
  <button type='button' id="stepUp">+</button>
  <input id="quantity" min="0" name="quantity" value="0" type="number" />
  <button type='button' id="stepDown">-</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var input = document.querySelector("#quantity");
  var parent = document.querySelector(".input-control");

  function alertQuantity(value) {
    if (value === '1') {
      alert('one');
    } else if (value === '0') {
      alert('zero');
    }
  }

  parent.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    if (target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
      if (target.id === 'stepUp') {
        input.stepUp();
      } else if (target.id === 'stepDown') {
        input.stepDown();
      }
      alertQuantity(input.value);
    }
  });

  input.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    alertQuantity(event.target.value);
  });
</script>
```

## How the snippet works

- I took the elements from the actual dom with the use of [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) API
- I just create a function called `alertQuantity` to create an abstraction and to avoid code redundancy for simple alerting purposes that we want to achieve
- Then I just create to simple event listeners with the use of `addEventListener()` to listen to parent `click` event and the input `change` event
- In the parent click event I simply checked which buttons get clicked and do the work accordingly
- Finally, I called the alerting function to alert our events

Comment: thanks I wanted to use this code inside asp.net file between java script brackets but it gives me error in const

Comment: @arater2000 Well, I'm not sure what error do you get exactly. But I will provide another snippet with ES5 syntax, within the `script` tags, hope it works.

Comment: thanks it worked for me after I added the java script code inside function and linked it with buttons using onclick but now I have an issue when I click plus button it increase the number every time I click it, for example at the beginning its 1 then 2 then  6 then 10 then 15 but it should increase like this: 1 then 2 then  3 then 4 then 5 etc

Comment: @arater2000 I guess, your implementation got some issues and I can't tell what are the issues. If you carefully look at the provided snippets, the snippets are working perfectly fine and I can't reproduce your issue here. For further debugging, you need to post your final code implementation for us.

Comment: @arater2000 Well, you messed things up there, first off, you do not need to add `onclick` handlers to the buttons (if you do this, you are actually calling the event 2x per click). To solve this, remove the `onclick` handlers from the buttons, move the script tag to the bottom of your file before the end of the `body` element after all the regular HTML codes (otherwise it will produce an error since you cant access nonexistent DOM elements), then remove the `validate3` function wrapper from your script tag and leave it how it was like the snippet that I provided before.